# Cross fade animation in react navigation tab navigator

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, bottomnavigationview

I am using react navigation tab navigator and react native material bottom navigation and it currently swipes from screen to screen. How would I make it cross fade from one screen to another like the Material Design Guidelines suggests.

**Router.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { TabNavigator, StackNavigator, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';
import { NavigationComponent } from 'react-native-material-bottom-navigation';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import { MAIN_COLOR, BOTTOM_BAR_COLOR, BOTTOM_BAR_ICON_COLOR } from '../config';
import { Classes, Settings, Search, SplashScreen } from '../components/screens';
import Login from '../components/screens/Login';
import Main from '../Main';

export const Tabs = TabNavigator({
  Classes: {
    screen: Classes,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Classes',
      tabBarIcon: () => <Icon size={24} name="list" color={BOTTOM_BAR_ICON_COLOR} />,
    },
  },
  Search: {
    screen: Search,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Search',
      tabBarIcon: () => <Icon size={24} name="search" color={BOTTOM_BAR_ICON_COLOR} />,
    },
  },
  Settings: {
    screen: Settings,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Settings',
      tabBarIcon: () => <Icon size={24} name="settings" color={BOTTOM_BAR_ICON_COLOR} />,
    },
  },
}, {
  tabBarComponent: NavigationComponent,
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
  swipeEnabled: false,
  tabBarOptions: {
    bottomNavigationOptions: {
      labelColor: BOTTOM_BAR_ICON_COLOR,
      rippleColor: MAIN_COLOR,
      shifting: false,
      tabs: {
        Search: {
          barBackgroundColor: BOTTOM_BAR_COLOR,
          activeIcon: <Icon size={24} name="search" color={MAIN_COLOR} />,
          activeLabelColor: MAIN_COLOR,
        },
        Classes: {
          barBackgroundColor: BOTTOM_BAR_COLOR,
          activeIcon: <Icon size={24} name="list" color={MAIN_COLOR} />,
          activeLabelColor: MAIN_COLOR,
        },
        Settings: {
          barBackgroundColor: BOTTOM_BAR_COLOR,
          activeIcon: <Icon size={24} name="settings" color={MAIN_COLOR} />,
          activeLabelColor: MAIN_COLOR,
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

**This is the effect I want**

https://storage.googleapis.com/material-design/publish/material_v_11/assets/0B3321sZLoP_HTTA0QUM4MWxKSTg/components_bottomnavigation_behavior_crossfade.webm

**This is what I have**

https://storage.googleapis.com/material-design/publish/material_v_11/assets/0B3321sZLoP_HQWYxQWE5LUg2WDQ/components_bottomnavigation_behavior_sibling.webm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed the error by disabling animation in the tab navigator.

Comment: Did you get the fade up effect? I am looking for the same.

Comment: set 'animationEnabled' to false inside the navigation options for your tab navigator

Comment: Your answer does not provide the cross fade animation asked about in the question...?